# Dropdown field is calling the function with an API Call indefinitely

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I have to populate a dropdown with the response of an API. The thing is that api takes few query parameters `X` and `Y` that are based on different fields in the screen that can be changed so I can not call the `getCategoryByXandY` API once at ngOnInIt().

Currently I have it working but as i select the dropdown, the `fetchCategories` function is being called again and again causing the API to be spammed. I read at different places that this is causing big performance issues but I cannot figure it out how to do it with Pure Pipes. Can someone help me if that's the right direction? and how so?

Service:

```
  @Injectable()
  export class CategoryRestService {
      private walletsUrl = 'api/items';
      constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
      ) {}
     ...
     getCategoryByXandY(X: string, Y: string): Observable<CategoryDto[]> {
       const url = `${this.itemUrl}/category/?param1=${X}&param2=${Y}`;
       return this.http.get<CategoryDto[]>(url);
     }
  }
```

HTML

```
    ...
    <mat-form-field fxFlex.gt-sm="31%" *ngIf="isRequired()">
            <mat-label>
                Category
            </mat-label>
            <mat-select
                formControlName="category"
                [required]="isRequired()">

                <mat-option
                    *ngFor="let c of fetchCategories()"
                    [value]="c.id">

                    {{c.name}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Component

```
 {
   categories: CategoryDto[]

   constructor(
      categoryService: CategoryRestService
   ){ } 

   ...

   fetchCategories() {
       const X = this.getControl('x').value;
       const Y = this.getControl('y').value;
       this.categoryService.getCategoryByXandY(x, y).subscribe(
          categories => {
             categories.filter(category => category.status === 'ACTIVE');
             this.categories = categories;
          }
       );
       return this.categories;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
In Addition to David's suggestion, I had a `.valueChange` on the form field of `x` and `y` to trigger the API and update `categories`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change let c of fetchCategories() to let c of categories. Point it to the dataset, not the function.

HTML

```
    <mat-form-field fxFlex.gt-sm="31%" *ngIf="isRequired()">
      <mat-label>
          Category
      </mat-label>
      <mat-select
          formControlName="category"
          [required]="isRequired()"
          >
          <mat-option
              *ngFor="let c of categories"
              [value]="c.id"
(click)="selected(c)"
>
              {{c.name}}
          </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Component

In the constructor or ngOnInit() add this

this.fetchCategories()

In your controller

```
selected(value:any){
console.log('selected value',value);
}
```

Comment: Hi David, i tried using take(1) and retry(1) and it didnt work. Isn't the problem here "let c of fetchCategories()"? where the fetchCategories is called over and over again and not the "this.categoryService.getCategoryByXandY"?

Comment: Yeah, I see it now. FetchCategories is a function and not a dataset

Comment: But then when would the dataset be populated? It needs to be fetched by the API when that dropdown is expanded?

Comment: you can do it one of two ways. When it loads through the ngOnInit() or in the constructor. Or when you first click the select then call the function through a (click)="fetchCategories()" in the mat-select. if it is a form I always do it through the ngOnInit or constructor when it loads depending on the scenario and what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yeah that's what i thought at first but the form is not yet populated it seems and i get null values from the form

Comment: I added in an example of what to do to get the selected value.